# What does ' ' (tow single quotations marks, one after the other, not the double that come together) do?

Tags: python

I'm printing this in Python (3.6)

```
print(' 'f' ')
```

and it shows nothing!
What is happening?

It sounds like whatever I put inside the inner ' ', vanish.

Comment: Try putting almost anything that isn't an `f` there, and you'll get a SyntaxError. For example, try it with a `g`.

Comment: Woah! you're right! I lied. So, what's going on?

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase my question: what is the point of this: print('    ''    ')?
It shows nothing! none of the two qoutation marks are showing up, and they don't declare the end of the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`' '` is a string literal representing a single space. This is something pretty much any Python programmer needs to be thoroughly familiar with.

`f' '` is an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). If there were any braces in there, it would do string interpolation, but there are no braces. Like `' '`, it ends up evaluating to a string representing a single space.

When two string literals appear side by side, Python implicitly concatenates them, as if you had used `+`, but with super-high precedence. This is an obscure feature that causes more bugs than it's worth.

Putting all that together, `' 'f' '` evaluates to a string containing two spaces, so you don't see anything when you print it, because you can't see spaces.

Comment: Voted up for professional critique of Python 
"This is an obscure feature that causes more bugs than it's worth."
Golden!

Answer (score 1):

You are actually defining two strings there.

1. `' '` - this is a normal space
2. `f' '` - this is an f-string or format string. Any string that's prefixed with `f` is an f-string. This one also happens to be just a space.

So you have two spaces. Side-by-side. Python implicitly concatenates the two strings to give you the result. So the result of print is also just 2 spaces.

If you wanted to print "f", you can do:

```
print(' \'f\' ')
```

You need to escape the single quotes.

Comment: Those aren't empty. `''` would be empty. `' '` has a space in it.

Comment: Yup you can do that in python. Python just concatenates the two string together and gives you the result.